# How to switch from LESS to SCSS in Meteor / Iron in an existing project

Tags: node.js, meteor, sass

I made a small project in **Meteor / Iron**. There's almost no styling in it yet but a lot of **JavaScript** already coded. I would like to update the system to handle **SCSS** instead of **LESS** since it seems more adapted for this specific project.

I can't find anywhere how to do such thing, do you have any idea ? Do I have to do everything manually ?

Comment: Well that's why i'm not talking about Meteor but Meteor / Iron which means this https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli and it seems there's no way to update a project ...

Comment: Oh. You mean like the `--css=scss` option on create, except for an existing project?

Comment: That's exactly what i mean yeah !

Comment: Could be relevant: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli/issues/222

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli#commands):

`$ iron create myApp --css=scss`

You could then dump everything but your `.scss` files into the new project.

Or you can manually swap out packages as mentioned above:

```
meteor remove less 
meteor add fourseven:scss
```

As far as converting your LESS into SASS, [this](http://nicoespeon.com/en/2013/06/convert-sass-project-into-less/) may help, but I dont think its going to be as automatic as you want.

Comment: hey man it's exactly this but in the other way (from less to scss) if you want me to valid your answer just reverse it for the next people to understand ;)

Comment: @Laurent glad to hear you got it worked out. thanks for the heads up. corrected!

Comment: @Laurent if you don't mind, id appreciate it if you marked the answer correct.